# Select Highest value in one column while showing other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building for fun/practice a database of Pokemon Go data. I have a table called Moveset that tracks the strength of each possible moveset for each Pokemon. Here's an ERD for the relevant part of my database:
[image: DB ERD]

Here's what some of the data in the Moveset table looks like:

```
Pokemon                        FastMove                       ChargeMove                     MovesetType                    TotalDpt               ShieldPressure
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------------- ----------------------
Charizard                      Air Slash                      Blast Burn                     Community Day                  11.52                  7.2
Charizard                      Air Slash                      Dragon Claw                    NULL                           7.89                   10.3
Charizard                      Air Slash                      Fire Blast                     NULL                           9.9                    4.5
Charizard                      Air Slash                      Flamethrower                   Limited                        9.49                   6.5
Charizard                      Air Slash                      Overheat                       NULL                           12.11                  6.5
Charizard                      Air Slash                      Return                         Limited                        9.17                   5.1
Charizard                      Ember                          Dragon Claw                    Limited                        7.89                   10.3
Charizard                      Ember                          Fire Blast                     Limited                        9.9                    4.5
Charizard                      Ember                          Flamethrower                   Limited                        9.49                   6.5
Charizard                      Ember                          Overheat                       Limited                        12.11                  6.5
Charizard                      Ember                          Return                         Limited                        9.17                   5.1
Charizard                      Fire Spin                      Blast Burn                     Community Day                  12.39                  8
Charizard                      Fire Spin                      Dragon Claw                    NULL                           8.36                   11.4
Charizard                      Fire Spin                      Fire Blast                     NULL                           10.59                  5
Charizard                      Fire Spin                      Flamethrower                   Limited                        10.14                  7.3
Charizard                      Fire Spin                      Overheat                       NULL                           13.05                  7.3
Charizard                      Fire Spin                      Return                         Limited                        9.78                   5.7
Charizard                      Wing Attack                    Dragon Claw                    Limited                        8                      12
Charizard                      Wing Attack                    Fire Blast                     Limited                        10.35                  5.3
Charizard                      Wing Attack                    Flamethrower                   Limited                        9.87                   7.6
Charizard                      Wing Attack                    Overheat                       Limited                        12.93                  7.6
Charizard                      Wing Attack                    Return                         Limited                        9.5                    6
Venusaur                       Razor Leaf                     Frenzy Plant                   Community Day                  11.93                  5.3
Venusaur                       Razor Leaf                     Petal Blizzard                 NULL                           10.66                  3.7
Venusaur                       Razor Leaf                     Return                         Limited                        10.31                  3.4
Venusaur                       Razor Leaf                     Sludge Bomb                    NULL                           10.44                  4.8
Venusaur                       Razor Leaf                     Solar Beam                     NULL                           11.1                   3
Venusaur                       Vine Whip                      Frenzy Plant                   Community Day                  13.67                  10.7
Venusaur                       Vine Whip                      Petal Blizzard                 NULL                           11.12                  7.4
Venusaur                       Vine Whip                      Return                         Limited                        10.43                  6.9
Venusaur                       Vine Whip                      Sludge Bomb                    NULL                           10.68                  9.6
Venusaur                       Vine Whip                      Solar Beam                     NULL                           12                     6
```

I'm trying to write a query that will return only the highest-DPT moveset for each Pokemon, but show all other data. So with that example data above, my desired output would look like this:

```
Pokemon                        FastMove                       ChargeMove                     MovesetType                    TotalDpt               ShieldPressure
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------------- ----------------------
Venusaur                       Vine Whip                      Frenzy Plant                   Community Day                  13.67                  10.7
Charizard                      Fire Spin                      Overheat                       NULL                           13.05                  7.3
```

I've tried using MAX(TotalDPT) in a query, but then I have to Group By every other field I want to show or it won't work. For example, I tried this:

```
Select Pokemon, FastMove, ChargeMove, MovesetType, MAX(TotalDpt), ShieldPressure
From Moveset
Group by Pokemon
```

However, that gives the following error:

> Column 'Moveset.FastMove' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Then I tried adding the columns to the Group By Clause:

```
Select Pokemon, FastMove, ChargeMove, MovesetType, MAX(TotalDpt), ShieldPressure
From Moveset
Group by Pokemon, FastMove, ChargeMove, MovesetType, ShieldPressure
Order By MAX(TotalDPT) desc
```

However, that just outputs all rows in the table. Then I tried this:

```
Select Pokemon, MovesetType, MAX(TotalDpt)
From Moveset
Group by Pokemon
Order By MAX(TotalDPT) desc
```

That gives me the highest TotalDPT for each Pokemon, but doesn't tell me what moveset they're using. The moves that give the TotalDPT are what I need to know most.

Comment: Google window function.

Comment: "I've tried using MAX(TotalDPT) in a query, but then I have to Group By every other field I want to show or it won't work." Why is this a problem?

Comment: Either `row_number` or `rank`

Comment: Edited to clarify what I've tried and why it doesn't meet my needs.

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get the max damage per Pokemon

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Pokemon, FastMove, ChargeMove, MovesetType, ShieldPressure, TotalDpt
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Pokemon ORDER BY TotalDPT DESC) AS rn
    FROM Moveset
) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The *simplest* solution in SQL Server is:

```
Select top (1) with ties Pokemon, FastMove, ChargeMove, MovesetType, MAX(TotalDpt), ShieldPressure
From Moveset
order by row_number() over (partition by Pokemon order by TotalDPT desc);
```

This is slightly less performant than other solutions (say using `row_number()` in a subquery or using a correlated query).